# jtree couldnt get index of specific node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i have jTree (for example):

```
-paper
    -coated
    -glossy
        -hummermill
        -quatro
        -springhill
    -matte
```

when i select springhill i get index of 5, but i dont want to count from the root(paper) (that includes parents and other nodes outside the glossy), i want to start counting from hummermill so i try to get index of 2.

i used `tree.getLeadSelectionRow()` and get int value of 5; also i use `node.getIndex(node)` but here i dont get anything normal (0,3,-1). I try all variations of all metods there is for node and tree and find nothing helpfull. plese help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to find the index of node from its parent

```
  DefaultMutableTreeNode node=(DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();

  System.out.println(node.getParent().getIndex(node));
```